# How I can solve this problem? "The argument type 'int?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'num'." (Dart)

Tags: dart

I'm trying to write a code which print the sum of odd and even numbers from a group of inputs, but it doesn't work and I think it's a null safety issue.
This is the code

```
   void main() {
      List numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];
      List odd = [];
      List even = [];
    
      for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        var z = numbers[i] % 2;
    
        if (z == 0) {
          even.add(numbers[i]);
        } //end if
    
        else {
          odd.add(numbers[i]);
        } //end else
    
      } //end for loop
    
      int sumOdd = 0;
      int sumEven = 0;
      
      for (int i = 0; i < odd.length; i++) {
        
        sumOdd = sumOdd + odd[i];
      }//end for
      
        for (int i = 0; i < even.length; i++) {
        
        sumEven = sumEven + even[i];
      }//end for
    
      print("sum of odds numbers = $sumOdd");
      print("sum of even numbers = $sumEven");
      
    } //end main
```

Answer (score 0):

i think its because you not specify the type of list.
by default it will define as a list of number.

but `int sumOdd = 0;` you define  as integer.

thats why you got error when run here :  `sumOdd = sumOdd + odd[i];`

`sumOdd`  is integer

`odd[i]` is number .

- solution:

```
List<int> numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];
List <int> even =[];
List<int> odd =[];
```

- second solution

you can parse `odd[i]` to integer